# Using inout keyword: is the parameter passed-by-reference or by copy-in copy-out (/call by value result)

Tags: swift2, inout

**Question:** Based on the information and discussion below: Are `inout` parameters *passed-by-reference* or *by copy-in copy-out*?

---

Based on the following SO threads, function parameters marked by the `inout` keyword is *passed by reference*:

- [Does inout/var parameter make any difference with reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263796/does-inout-parameter-make-any-difference-with-reference-type)
- [Is Swift Pass By Value or Pass By Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)
- [Why doesn't inout pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879757/why-doesnt-inout-pass-by-reference)

We note that the two top-most threads are pre-Swift 2.0; I haven't been able to find any newer discussion on the subject here on SO (except the somewhat related third thread link).

---

Based on Apple's documentation (as far as I've been able to discern), however, function parameters marked by the `inout` keyword is passed by *copy-in copy-out* (or *call by value result*)

- [Apple Language Reference: Declarations - In-Out Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545):

> In-out parameters are passed as follows:
>
> When the function is called, **the value of the argument is copied**. In
>   the body of the function, **the copy is modified**. When the function
>   returns, **the copy’s value is assigned to the original argument**. This
>   behavior is known as **copy-in copy-out** or call by value result. ...

- [Apple Language Guide: Functions - In-Out Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html):

> ... You write an in-out parameter by placing the inout keyword at the
>   start of its parameter definition. An in-out parameter has a value
>   that is **passed in to the function**, is modified by the function,
>   and is **passed back out of the function to replace the original
>   value**. ...

---

Now for my own example trying to investigate this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    private var myInt: Int

    mutating func increaseMyInt() {
        myInt++
    }

    func printMyInt() {
        print(String(myInt))
    }

    init(int: Int) {
        myInt = int
    }
}

class MyClass {
    var myStruct: MyStruct

    init(int: Int) {
        myStruct = MyStruct(int: 1)
    }

    func printMyStructsInt() {
        print(String(myStruct.printMyInt()))
    }
}

func myInOutFunc(inout myLocalStruct: MyStruct, myClass: MyClass) -> Int {
    myClass.printMyStructsInt() // prints "1", OK
    myLocalStruct.increaseMyInt()
    myClass.printMyStructsInt() // prints "2": so myStruct is not a copy here?
    myLocalStruct.increaseMyInt()

    return 0
        // according to Apple's doc, shouldn't myStruct member of myClass get
        // assigned (copy of) value of myLocalStruct at this point, and not
        // prior to this?
}

var a = MyClass(int: 1)

a.printMyStructsInt() // prints "1", OK
myInOutFunc(&a.myStruct, myClass: a)
a.printMyStructsInt() // prints "3", OK
```

This example would imply that `inout` parameters are indeed passed by reference (as is noted in the two linked SO threads above). Since we prefix the inout parameter with an ampersand (`&`) this does "feel" logical.

To try my best to make sure that my example is representative---since here `inout` parameter `myLocalStruct` is sent as class property---I also made sure that the `myLocalStruct` didn't get some *"behind-the-hood"* reference due to it being a class property:

```
// ... add to bottom of the code above

func testSendStructAsPublicClassProperty(var myLocalStruct: MyStruct) {
    myLocalStruct.increaseMyInt()
}

// test that sending class property doesn't "reference" things up
a.printMyStructsInt() // prints "3"
testSendStructAsPublicClassProperty(a.myStruct)
a.printMyStructsInt() // prints "3", OK (only copy of class property is sent)
```

Ok, `myLocalStruct` in this example really function-local, and hence passed by value (no reference-behind-the-hood).

---

**Result:** Given the above, `inout` parameters are passed by reference?

I have two possible follow-up questions:

1. Have I misinterpreted the description on `inout` in the Apple language doc, can it be interpreted as "pass by reference"?
2. Or, is my example still not representative for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next two paragraphs in the Language Reference describes it more in detail:

> ## In-Out Parameters
>
> …
>
> This behavior is known as copy-in copy-out or call by value result. For
>   example, when a computed property or a property with observers is
>   passed as an in-out parameter, its getter is called as part of the
>   function call and its setter is called as part of the function return.
>
> As an optimization, when the argument is a value stored at a physical
>   address in memory, the same memory location is used both inside and
>   outside the function body. **The optimized behavior is known as call by
>   reference**; it satisfies all of the requirements of the copy-in
>   copy-out model while removing the overhead of copying. **Do not depend
>   on the behavioral differences between copy-in copy-out and call by
>   reference.**

So it's de facto "pass by reference"

Comment: Ah, I skimmed over that part, thanks! If possible, perhaps you can boldmark also the last sentence in your citation above? It's quite a punch-line w.r.t. the context of my question :)