# When to use inout parameters?

Tags: swift, swift2

When passing a class or primitive type into a function, any change made in the function to the parameter will be reflected outside of the class. This is basically the same thing an `inout` parameter is supposed to do.

What is a good use case for an inout parameter?

Comment: Are you sure that this happens with a primitive type that you pass in as a "regular" parameter as well?

Comment: Do you have a code example that shows where Swift behaves like you describe?

Comment: See my sample @Thilo

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`inout` means that modifying the local variable will also modify the passed-in parameters. Without it, the passed-in parameters will remain the same value. Trying to think of reference type when you are using `inout` and value type without using it.

For example:

```
import UIKit

var num1: Int = 1
var char1: Character = "a"

func changeNumber(var num: Int) {
    num = 2
    print(num) // 2
    print(num1) // 1
}
changeNumber(num1)

func changeChar(inout char: Character) {
    char = "b"
    print(char) // b
    print(char1) // b
}
changeChar(&char1)
```

A good use case will be `swap` function that it will modify the passed-in parameters.

**Swift 3+ Note**: [Starting in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0031-adjusting-inout-declarations.md), the `inout` keyword must come *after* the colon and before the type. For example, Swift 3+ now requires `func changeChar(char: inout Character)`.

Comment: Is that well-defined behaviour? Because the spec seems to say that `inout` gets copied back when the function returns. So should `char1` already be  `a` within the function?

Comment: Re: well-defined behaviour: @drfi's answer addresses this: "Do not depend on the behavioral differences between copy-in copy-out and call by reference"

Comment: @Thilo You are correct, this example contains code that may not behave well-defined, and at the very least are not in line with the `inout` language ref. I'll add an example into my answer.

Comment: Note that `var` in your `changeNumber` function will be deprecated in future versions of Swift.

Comment: It's just an example to show the differences. It's not for actual practice.

Comment: calling `changeNumber(num1)` causes the error. "Simultaneous accesses to 0x7fe71270a578, but modification requires exclusive access."
checking on Xcode 11.4.1

Answer (score 48):

From [Apple Language Reference: Declarations - In-Out Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545):

> As an optimization, when the argument is a value stored at a physical
>   address in memory, the same memory location is used both inside and
>   outside the function body. The optimized behavior is known as call by
>   reference; it satisfies all of the requirements of the copy-in
>   copy-out model **while removing the overhead of copying**. Do not depend
>   on the behavioral differences between copy-in copy-out and call by
>   reference.

If you have a function that takes a somewhat memory-wise large value type as argument (say, a large structure type) and that returns the same type, and finally where the function return is always used just to replace the caller argument, then `inout` is to prefer as associated function parameter.

Consider the example below, where comments describe why we would want to use `inout` over a regular type-in-return-type function here:

```
struct MyStruct {
    private var myInt: Int = 1

    // ... lots and lots of stored properties

    mutating func increaseMyInt() {
        myInt += 1
    }
}

/* call to function _copies_ argument to function property 'myHugeStruct' (copy 1)
   function property is mutated
   function returns a copy of mutated property to caller (copy 2) */
func myFunc(var myHugeStruct: MyStruct) -> MyStruct {
    myHugeStruct.increaseMyInt()
    return myHugeStruct
}

/* call-by-reference, no value copy overhead due to inout opimization */
func myFuncWithLessCopyOverhead(inout myHugeStruct: MyStruct) {
    myHugeStruct.increaseMyInt()
}

var a = MyStruct()
a = myFunc(a) // copy, copy: overhead
myFuncWithLessCopyOverhead(&a) // call by reference: no memory reallocation
```

Also, in the example above---disregarding memory issues---`inout` can be preferred simply as a good code practice of telling whomever read our code that we are mutating the function caller argument (implicitly shown by the ampersand `&` preceding the argument in the function call). The following summarises this quite neatly:

> If you want a function to modify a parameter’s value, and you want
>   those changes to persist after the function call has ended, define
>   that parameter as an in-out parameter instead.

From [Apple Language Guide: Functions - In-Out Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

---

For details regarding `inout` and how it's actually handled in memory (name `copy-in-copy-out` is somewhat misleading...)---in additional to the links to the language guide above---see the following SO thread:

- [Using inout keyword: is the parameter passed-by-reference or by copy-in copy-out (/call by value result)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400600/using-inout-keyword-is-the-parameter-passed-by-reference-or-by-copy-in-copy-out)

---

*(Edit addition: An additional note)*

The example given in the accepted answer by Lucas Huang above tries to---in the scope of the function using an `inout` argument---access the variables that were passed as the `inout` arguments. This is not recommended, and is explicitly warned not to do in the language ref:

> **Do not access the value that was passed as an in-out argument, even if
>   the original argument is available in the current scope**. When the
>   function returns, your changes to the original are overwritten with
>   the value of the copy. **Do not depend on the implementation of the
>   call-by-reference optimization to try to keep the changes from being
>   overwritten**.

Now, the access in this case is "only" non-mutable, e.g. `print(...)`, but all access like this should, by convention, be avoided.

At request from a commenter, I'll add an example to shine light upon why we shouldn't really do anything with *"the value that was passed as an in-out argument"*.

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myStructsIntProperty: Int = 1

    mutating func myNotVeryThoughtThroughInoutFunction (inout myInt: Int) {
        myStructsIntProperty += 1
        /* What happens here? 'myInt' inout parameter is passed to this
           function by argument 'myStructsIntProperty' from _this_ instance
           of the MyStruct structure. Hence, we're trying to increase the
           value of the inout argument. Since the swift docs describe inout 
           as a "call by reference" type as well as a "copy-in-copy-out"
           method, this behaviour is somewhat undefined (at least avoidable).

           After the function has been called: will the value of
           myStructsIntProperty have been increased by 1 or 2? (answer: 1) */
        myInt += 1
    }

    func myInoutFunction (inout myInt: Int) {
        myInt += 1
    }
}

var a = MyStruct()
print(a.myStructsIntProperty) // 1
a.myInoutFunction(&a.myStructsIntProperty)
print(a.myStructsIntProperty) // 2
a.myNotVeryThoughtThroughInoutFunction(&a.myStructsIntProperty)
print(a.myStructsIntProperty) // 3 or 4? prints 3.
```

So, in this case, the inout behaves as copy-in-copy-out (and not by reference). We summarize by repeating the following statement from the language ref docs:

> Do not depend on the behavioral differences between copy-in copy-out
>   and call by reference.

Comment: I had trouble in understanding `Do not access the value that was passed as an in-out argument` statement, why is that, could you give an example? From what I understand, an argument, no matter inout or not, is first used to be accessed inside the function, otherwise we don't need the argument at all.

Comment: Sure, I'll add an example into the answer.

Comment: This has to be the right answer. Thanks for the detailed comment.

Comment: While an interesting experiment, this answer does not address the OP's only question: "What is a good use case for an inout parameter?" Also, Swift 5 will produce an error with the above code, preventing you from even entering a situation where you have competing/compounding by-ref and copy-in/copy-out value changes.

Answer (score 26):

Function parameters are constants by default. Trying to change the value of a function parameter from within the body of that function results in a compile-time error. This means that you can’t change the value of a parameter by mistake. If you want a function to modify a parameter’s value, and you want those changes to persist after the function call has ended, define that parameter as an in-out parameter instead.

[image: see image below for Description]

Comment: Nice example, though you should note that the copy is straight from the Swift docs.

Comment: Function parameters are constant by default when it is primitive data type.

Answer (score 1):

**inout param: modifies passing and local variable values.**

```
func doubleInPlace(number: inout Int) {
     number *= 2
     print(number) 
    
 }

 var myNum = 10 doubleInPlace(number: &myNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

inout parameter allow us to change the data of a value type parameter and to keep changes still after the function call has finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with classes then, as you say, you can modify the class because the parameter is a reference to the class. But this won't work when your parameter is a value type (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html - In-Out Parameters Section)

One good example of using inout is this one (defining math for CGPoints):

```
func + (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}

func += (left: inout CGPoint, right: CGPoint) {
  left = left + right
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is useful when you want to play with addresses of variable its very useful in data structure algorithms

Answer (score 0):

when use inout  parameter swift 4.0 Work

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var total:Int = 100

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.paramTotal(total1: &total)
    }

    func paramTotal(total1 :inout Int) {
        total1 = 111
        print("Total1 ==> \(total1)")
        print("Total ==> \(total)")
    }
}
```