# inout Declarations for Type Decoration

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a question according usage of the `inout` in Swift 3.

As i understand `inout` is quite expensive operation for use.

And there is question when and why it is better to use `inout` declaration?

regular function:

```
func double(input: Int)  {
    var input = input
    input = input * 2
}
```

`inout` declaration use:

```
func double(input: inout Int) {
    input = input * 2
}
```

Comment: `inout is quite expensive operation for use` Why do you say that?

Comment: I edit my answer. The source of the expensive is by this link https://realm.io/news/appbuilders-daniel-steinberg-whats-new-swift-3/. Section 0035

Comment: And now that you've edited: your first example *does nothing*. `input` is a *copy*. If you want to modify the original, use the second example with inout. This is not the same!

Comment: So it is just syntax sugar that gives opportunity to modify input property without reassigning ?

Comment: Yes. With inout you "tunnel" the existing variable into the function and you modify it from there. Whereas with your first example you're just copying the variable and modifying the copy - and since you don't return it, nothing happens, actually.

Comment: Hmm thx i will reformat my question could you please answer that is just syntax  sugar.Thanks for your attention

Comment: You're welcome. Yes give me 10 minutes I'm writing an answer.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34486250/1187415 which has a quotation and link to the Swift reference. "Simple variables" are just passed by reference.

Comment: Grate explain where to use inout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, this is a classic trap! :)

Your two functions are not doing the same thing, so one is not "better" than the other.

Your first one:

```
func double(input: Int)  {
    var input = input
    input = input * 2
}
```

does nothing.

Because with `var input = input` you are making a *copy* of the input value, so when you do `input = input * 2` you are just modifying the local copy, and since you don't return it, it is discarded and this function has no effect in the end.

Your second one:

```
func double(input: inout Int) {
    input = input * 2
}
```

does something: it modifies the original value because `inout` is a way of passing a value by reference. No need to make a copy and return it: the variable itself, the one you pass to the function, will be changed.

*Note: I suggest you read Martin R's excellent link where `inout` is very well explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486250/1187415*.