# ViewModel function: Cannot assign to value: 'error' is a 'let' constant

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to learn swift `ViewModel` and I have created a function to handel the error.

But when I call the function in my `ViewController` file it says :

```
Cannot assign to value: 'error' is a 'let' constant
```

Is there any way to fix this? I am still a student looking for the best advice.

Thanks a lot.

Below is my code can you guys please help me.

**SignUpError.swift :**

```
class SingUpError {
    func errorMessage(name: String?, lastName: String?,email: String?, password: String?, error: String?){

        enum ErrorMessage: String {
            case noName = "Name cannot be empty"
            case noLastName = "Last name cannot be empty"
            case noEmail = "Email cannot be empty"
            case noPassword = "Password cannot be empty"
        }

        if name == "" {
            error = ErrorMessage.noName.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

**NewUserVC.swift :**

```
class NewUserVC: UIViewController {

    // Var
    var vm = SingUpError()

    // Outlet Text Fields

    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UITextField!

    // Outlet Labels

    @IBOutlet weak var nameErrLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameErrLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailErrLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordErrLbl: UILabel!


    @IBAction func submiButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        submitData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func submitData() {
        guard
            let name = nameText.text,
            let lastName = lastNameText.text,
            let email = emailText.text,
            let password = passwordText.text
            else {return}

        vm.errorMessage(name: name, lastName: lastName, email: email, password: password, error: nameErrLbl.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't really tell what you are trying to do, but your code is attempting to mutate the constant value passed as an argument, which you can't do and has no effect anyway.  Are you trying to return an error?

Comment: I am trying to return an error, if the textfield is empty it will return an error...

Comment: Above Function is not return anything, change that aslo

Comment: What about trying to set input `error` as a `inout`? You should be able to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with `SingUpError` (do you mean `SignUpError`?) but this is my attempt at it. Basically I am moving the enum out of the func and I make the func return a String

```
class SingUpError  {
    enum ErrorMessage: String {
        case noName = "Name cannot be empty"
        case noLastName = "Last name cannot be empty"
        case noEmail = "Email cannot be empty"
        case noPassword = "Password cannot be empty"
    }

    func errorMessage(name: String?, lastName: String?,email: String?, password: String?) -> String? {
        var message: String?

        if name == nil || name.isEmpty {
            message = ErrorMessage.noName.rawValue
        } //else if lastName...

        return message
    }
}
```

and then in `submitData`

```
if let error = vm.errorMessage(name: name, lastName: lastName, email: email, password: password) {
     nameErrLbl.text = error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to do something like this**

```
class SingUpError {
    func errorMessage(name: String?, lastName: String?,email: String?, password: String?, error: String?) -> String{

        var errorMessage : String = ""

        enum ErrorMessage: String {
            case noName = "Name cannot be empty"
            case noLastName = "Last name cannot be empty"
            case noEmail = "Email cannot be empty"
            case noPassword = "Password cannot be empty"
        }

        if name == "" {
            errorMessage = ErrorMessage.noName.rawValue
        }

        return errorMessage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function on swift, its parameters are by default 'let' constants. And we can not assign value to constants.

In your case, you are trying to assign to 'error' variable, which is a parameter, hence a constant(let). You can not do that.

**You could return an error message**

```
class SingUpError {
    func errorMessage(name: String?, lastName: String?,email: String?, password: String?) -> String{

        enum ErrorMessage: String {
            case noName = "Name cannot be empty"
            case noLastName = "Last name cannot be empty"
            case noEmail = "Email cannot be empty"
            case noPassword = "Password cannot be empty"
        }

        if name == "" {
            return ErrorMessage.noName.rawValue
        }

        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: return string is required at last otherwise it gives error "Missing return in a function expected to return String "

Comment: Yes, that is correct. We need to return a string. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to assign value to constant.

You can't do that, because `error` it's parameter of function.
If you want to get error message from this function you need to write something like:

```
return ErrorMessage.noName.rawValue
```

instead

```
error = ErrorMessage.noName.rawValue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class SingUpError {
    func errorMessage(name: String?, lastName: String?,email: String?, password: String?) -> String? {

        guard let _ = name else { return ErrorMessage.noName.rawValue }

        // <this seems incomplete, but..>
        enum ErrorMessage: String { 
            case noName = "Name cannot be empty"
            case noLastName = "Last name cannot be empty"
            case noEmail = "Email cannot be empty"
            case noPassword = "Password cannot be empty"
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, put this enum out of the class SignUpError

```
enum ErrorMessage: String {
        case noName = "Name cannot be empty"
        case noLastName = "Last name cannot be empty"
        case noEmail = "Email cannot be empty"
        case noPassword = "Password cannot be empty"
    }
```

secondly, you can modify your function like this:

```
func errorMessage(name: String?, lastName: String?,email: String?, password: String?) -> String? {
    if name == "" {
        let error = ErrorMessage.noName.rawValue
        return error
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now in your ViewController, you can modify your function to get the errorMessage like this

```
func submitData() {
    //YOUR EXISTING CODE HERE    
    if let errorMessage = vm.errorMessage(name: name, lastName: lastName, email: email, password: password) {
        print("errorMessage:\(errorMessage)")
        return
    }
}
```

OR You can try the same approach you are having but by passing error as inout parameter. [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486052/when-to-use-inout-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have said you can't assign to the 'error' parameter because it is a constant (a let variable if you will).  Now you can go down the route of modifyig the function to return as string as suggested but you would be better off adopting a more structured approach and actually throwing an error.

Something like this would do:

```
enum sumbissionErrors: Error {
    case noName
    case noLastName
    case noEmail
    case noPassword

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .noName:
            return "Name cannot be empty"
        case .noLastName:
            return "Last name cannot be empty"
        case .noEmail:
            return "Email cannot be empty"
        case .noPassword:
            return "Password cannot be empty"
        }
    }
}

func submitData() throws {
    if nameText.text == nil || nameText.text!.isEmpty {
        throw sumbissionErrors.noName
    }

    if lastNameText.text == nil || lastNameText.text!.isEmpty {
        throw sumbissionErrors.noLastName
    }

    if emailText.text == nil || emailText.text!.isEmpty {
        throw sumbissionErrors.noEmail
    }

    if passwordText.text == nil || passwordText.text!.isEmpty {
        throw sumbissionErrors.noPassword
    }

    // Do whatever you want now that the data is valid.
}

@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    do {
        try submitData()
    }
    catch {
        if let sumbmissionError = error as? sumbissionErrors {
            switch sumbmissionError {
            case .noName:
                nameErrLbl.text = sumbmissionError.description
            case .noLastName:
                lastNameErrLbl.text = sumbmissionError.description
            case .noEmail:
                emailErrLbl.text = sumbmissionError.description
            case .noPassword:
                passwordErrLbl.text = sumbmissionError.description
            }
        } else {
            // This will probably never happen but it indicates that some other more general error occured and needs to be handled here.
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example and like your original will only throw the first error it comes across.  You might want to re-structure everything to allow multiple errors to be flagged.  I.e. it's possible that more than one of them could be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with same approach you used then you need to change some minor thing in your function.

First thing function parameter is let constant means you cannot assign the value but if you still need to assign some value to your parameter then there will be one way used **inout** keyword in function

```
class SingUpError {
    func errorMessage(name: String?, lastName: String?,email: String?, password: String?, error: inout String?){

        enum ErrorMessage: String {
            case noName = "Name cannot be empty"
            case noLastName = "Last name cannot be empty"
            case noEmail = "Email cannot be empty"
            case noPassword = "Password cannot be empty"
        }

        if name == "" {
            error = ErrorMessage.noName.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

calling

```
vm.errorMessage(name: name, lastName: lastName, email: email, password: password, error: &nameErrLbl.text)
```

Here is some reference link too

[When to use inout parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486052/when-to-use-inout-parameters)