# inout parameter in Swift

Tags: swift

When trying to study ionut parameters, I came across an example of
[code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486052/when-to-use-inout-parameters/43783754).

This code throws an error:

> "Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT. The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation."

However, when trying to debag on a real project, po char 1.

```
var num1: Int = 1
var char1 = "a"

func changeNumber(num: Int) {
    var num = num
    num = 2
    print(num) // 2
    print(num1) // 1
}
changeNumber(num: num1)

func changeChar(char: inout String) {
    char = "b"
    print(char) // b
    print(char1) // b
}
changeChar(char: &char1)
```

Please explain why this error is issued and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error should be at the top of the stack trace:

```
Simultaneous accesses to 0x109fac098, but modification requires exclusive access.
```

When you pass `char1` as a `inout` parameter to `changeChar` it is a memory violation to access `char1` in any other way until that function returns.

For full details, see [SE-176 Enforce Exclusive Access to Memory](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md) which added this restriction in Swift 4.

Comment: Yes, thank you, now I understand. Just inside the function, you can not access the char 1 variable. I will now know this.