# Is `inout` the correct way to prevent large array copies when passing parameters?

Tags: swift, memory-management

I would like to check my understanding of the `inout` parameter. Assume this `adt()` function is going to be called millions of times on a very very large array, lets say 10mb array. Adding the `inout` parameter in this example, will prevent the 10mb array being duplicated in memory millions of times over and over again? Is that correct?

```
import Foundation

func adt(_ d: inout [UInt8], _ i:UInt8) {
    d.append(i)
}

var d:[UInt8] = []
adt(&d,1)
adt(&d,2)
adt(&d,3)
```

I understand that `inout` is the correct way to allow parameters outside the function to be modified, but I cant find documentation on how the memory is managed in this situation.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486052/when-to-use-inout-parameters) could be helpful.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID362

Comment: Sure, this is better than passing an array by value... But why not encapsulate it in a class instead: `class ArrayHandler { private var d: [UInt8] = []; func adt(_ i: UInt8) { d.append(i) }` - no copying big arrays, and if tomorrow you need to make any changes - for example make an array thread-safe, you have better chance to do so if it's encapsulated.

Comment: Thanks @jjquirckart I was only intending to communicate some sample code that demonstrated usage of `inout`. I am not sure if the real code can be refectory this way, I will see what I can do, thanks!